# Visitor is unable to run a simple workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a very simple workflow.  two stages and it just assigns variables internally.   I can not run this workflow from a user in the visitors group.  The workflow is on a custom list of which the user has contribute rights.  The task and history lists associated to this flow is also at the contribute level.  I also added the first stage of the workflow to be an app step.

The workflow runs fine for members and owners, but for visitors it does not.  I have the following error on the workflow:

Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to .https://share.health.wisconsin.gov/hc/teams/BSM/DMSDataManagement/_api/web/lists(guid'447d7c22-464a-477d-892b-61025e2dc210') Correlation Id: 1baeb324-b14a-43fa-9f1f-40531a44565c Instance Id: 95085cb3-c116-4a03-b0f7-`1ff8ae2fb8ba

If I try to have the user manually run the workflow, the workflows do not show.
I really do not know what else to try.  Any ideas why a workflow is not working in this case?

Comment: The error message is about Permission issue. What actions did you use in your workflow? Please provide more details, i will try to repro this issue on my end.

Comment: That's the fascinating thing about this wf.  All I do is set 1 variable to a constant.  I reduced it to a simple assignment of a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching and testing I have found the solution.  It might not be the solution in all cases, but it works for me.

For a workflow to auto start with a new or an update, the user must have the following minimum security access.  Contribute (edit and delete) on the following lists:
The list/library in question and
the associated Tasks and History for the workflow

The workflow will auto fire.  The user can not manually start the workflow, or see the status of the workflows, but they will run.